# how to restart searching AsyncTask thread when Edditext onTextChanged()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-edittext, textchanged

I'm coding an android dictionary app. But I get this error:
When I'm typing in EditText I'll call onTextChanged(), in this method I execute an AsyncTask thread. Every time I'm typing a characters, app will call onTextChange() and execute AsyncTask. For example, i'am typing "da" app will search "da%" this word in database, I continue type "dat" it will start a new AsyncTask thread and search "dat%" in DB. But 2 thread was created and search in DB, it will execute the first thread before return the second thread (I want to stop thread 1 before execute thread 2). These issues makes my app running very slow.

This is my code:

Function of the EditText:

```
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                keyword = txtKeyword.getText().toString().trim();
                new Searching().execute("500");
           }
        });
```

The AsyncTask class:

```
private class Searching extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   publishProgress("Searching...");
   try {
       searchlist = search(keyword);//this method will search in DB (SELECT * FFROM dictionary where word like 'da%';)
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    resp = e.getMessage();
   }
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   adapter.setListView(searchlist);
   lvData.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  }
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
        txtResult.setText(text[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IntentService instead because it doesn't interfere with UI directly and in addition it will execute job requests in queue. 
Benefits;
- Your app will run at least smoother
- multiple requests will be executed sequentially 
Read more here; 
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html#CreateClass

Answer (score 0):

Your performance issues are likely to have more to do with your `LIKE` query, which doesn't use an index. If you need this type of query consider setting a limit on the number of results, if you are not already.

Perhaps instead consider using FTS as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html).

Consider using this in conjunction with an asynchronous cursor [`LoaderManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) which in addition can handle the lifetime of the cursor for you.

All told if you go this route you might find you do not need to cancel a query once it's in flight.